# Event listener not working in external file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When my JavaScript code is on the same HTML page, event listener is working:

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropBtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   </div>
 </div>
  
  <script>
    
  
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropBtn");
  
  function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
  
  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }

 
    </script>
```

But when I put same javascript code into external JS file, the event listener is not working.

I included JS file just before closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

How to make my event listener works from an external file, not just inside HTML page ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console when you include the script externally?

Comment: Your javascript isn't failing because it's in its own file. Is your file path correct?

Comment: For testing purpose i put: window.onload=function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
} in main.js file.....and it's working on my index.html, but not at the other HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the window.onload() function.

It should be:

```
window.onload = function () {

var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropBtn");

    function myFunction() {
         document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    dropdown.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Also, if this is an external JS, you should not include the `<script>` tags.